# How to commit code in multiple branches in Source Tree

Tags: branching-and-merging, atlassian-sourcetree

I have some code which I have already committed in say branch X. How do I commit the same code in Branch Y ? Is there any way to commit same code in multiple branches at the same time?

Comment: Are you using git or mercurial? In general you cannot (or would not want to) commit to multiple branches at the same time because that defeats the purpose concept of isolated branches of development. You can bundle the changesets that you want to merge into another branch and then go merge the bundle changesets. Or you can commit the changes you want, go to the other repository and pull from the repository you just changed into the one you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the same commit using cherry-pick on you new branch.

Doc:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Explained:
http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html